# How to disable the positivebutton of an AlertDialog during runtime?

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there a way to disable the positivebutton of an AlertDialog during runtime,say from within a TextWatcher?

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(getString(R.string.createvfs))
                    .setView(newVSView_v11)
                    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.okay),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {
                                    // Canceled.
                                }
                            }).show();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to obtain a reference to the dialog itself in order to modify it later, so you'll have to change your builder a little, but then you can call `AlertDialog.getButton()` to enable or disable the button anytime you like.  Something like this...

```
//Use create() so you can get the instance back
AlertDialog dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.createvfs))
                .setView(newVSView_v11)
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.okay),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                // Canceled.
                            }
                        }).create();
//Then show it
dialog.show();

/* ...Sometime in the distance future... */
dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
```

If you want to actually make the button invisible, that's slightly more difficult.  I can't test at the moment whether calling `setVisibility()` on the button will produce good results or not...

HTH

Comment: I hust want to disable the button, I tried your code but it fs because dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) returns null. :S